# TypeError at /admin/blog/entry/add/ - Python 2.7

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I'm a beginner and I'm having this error while trying to do this tutorial: [Link Tutorial Blog Django](http://arunrocks.com/recreating-the-building-a-blog-in-django-screencast/). Please help me solve this problem. I suspect that it may be related to the use of the Markdown package.

**The Environment:**

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/blog/entry/add/

Django Version: 1.11.7
Python Version: 2.7.12
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'blog',
 'django_markdown']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']
```

**Template error:**

```
In template /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/includes/fieldset.html, error at line 19
   context must be a dict rather than Context.   9 :             {% for field in line %}
   10 :                 <div{% if not line.fields|length_is:'1' %} class="field-box{% if field.field.name %} field-{{ field.field.name }}{% endif %}{% if not field.is_readonly and field.errors %} errors{% endif %}{% if field.field.is_hidden %} hidden{% endif %}"{% elif field.is_checkbox %} class="checkbox-row"{% endif %}>
   11 :                     {% if not line.fields|length_is:'1' and not field.is_readonly %}{{ field.errors }}{% endif %}
   12 :                     {% if field.is_checkbox %}
   13 :                         {{ field.field }}{{ field.label_tag }}
   14 :                     {% else %}
   15 :                         {{ field.label_tag }}
   16 :                         {% if field.is_readonly %}
   17 :                             <div class="readonly">{{ field.contents }}</div>
   18 :                         {% else %}
   19 :                              {{ field.field }} 
   20 :                         {% endif %}
   21 :                     {% endif %}
   22 :                     {% if field.field.help_text %}
   23 :                         <div class="help">{{ field.field.help_text|safe }}</div>
   24 :                     {% endif %}
   25 :                 </div>
   26 :             {% endfor %}
   27 :         </div>
   28 :     {% endfor %}
   29 : </fieldset>
```

**The Traceback:**

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  217.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  215.                 response = response.render()

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/response.py" in render
  107.             self.content = self.rendered_content

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/response.py" in rendered_content
  84.         content = template.render(context, self._request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/backends/django.py" in render
  66.             return self.template.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  207.                     return self._render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  177.             return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  177.             return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  72.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  72.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  216.                     nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  216.                 return template.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  209.                 return self._render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  216.                     nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  216.                     nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  322.                 return nodelist.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  322.                 return nodelist.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  1046.         return render_value_in_context(output, context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_value_in_context
  1024.     value = force_text(value)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/encoding.py" in force_text
  78.                 s = six.text_type(s)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/html.py" in <lambda>
  376.         klass.__unicode__ = lambda self: mark_safe(klass_unicode(self))

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/boundfield.py" in __str__
  41.         return self.as_widget()

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/boundfield.py" in as_widget
  127.             **kwargs

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_markdown/widgets.py" in render
  38.         html += editor_js_initialization("#%s" % attrs['id'])

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_markdown/utils.py" in editor_js_initialization
  47.     return INIT_TEMPLATE.render(ctx)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/backends/django.py" in render
  64.         context = make_context(context, request, autoescape=self.backend.engine.autoescape)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/context.py" in make_context
  287.         raise TypeError('context must be a dict rather than %s.' % context.__class__.__name__)

Exception Type: TypeError at /admin/blog/entry/add/
Exception Value: context must be a dict rather than Context.
```

Here is some useful information to solve the problem.

Comment: Note that the tutorial is written for Django 1.7, so it's really out of date.

Answer (score 1):

As you suspect, the django-markdown package is the problem. The tutorial is written for Django 1.7 but you are using Django 1.11. The django-markdown library does not support Django 1.11.

I recommend you look for a different tutorial. Django 1.7 is several years old, and lots has changed since then.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion for a more recent tutorial?

Comment: Try the official tutorial or Django Girls tutorial.